# Как получить результат сложения текстовых полей в Java

Tags: java, swing

как получить результат сложения  из `jTextField1` и `jTextField2` по нажатию кнопки `jButton1` и вывести результат в `jTextField3` ?

P. S.  не судите строго

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
vesSportsmena = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText()); //читаем с текстового поля текст, преобразуем в Double
}
private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
vesSportsmena = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText()); //читаем с текстового поля текст, преобразуем в Double
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
result =  vesSportsmena + vremyaProbejki; 
} 
private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String str = Double.toString(result);
jTextField3.setText(str); //вывожу обратно результат в текстовое поле
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен объект - обработчик события который реализует интерфейс ActionListener, в этом объекте реализуется метод public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}, далее нужна сама кнопка Button b = new Button("Click me"); к этой кнопке надо добавить слушателя b.addActionListener(object that implements ActionListener); туториал - (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: @Илья Шашилов можете правильно переформулировать мой вопрос

Comment: вроде ваш вопрос сформулирован Вами уже, давайте лучше разбираться дальше. У вас сейчас 4 разных ActionPerformed, тем более с вашими префиксами, так не пойдет. Достаточно одного метода ActionPerformed в котором всю логику по обработке события нажатия кнопки можно произвести. Скажите эти ваши 4 разных ActionPerformed, это у вас методы какого класса? И второе кнопки и текстовое поле где то существуют?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно добавить слушатель на вашу кнопку `click`, где `f1`, `f2` - текстовые поля `jTextField` с числами, а `f3` - `jTextField`, куда вы хотите записать ответ:

```
click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Integer s = Integer.parseInt(f1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(f2.getText());
        f3.setText(s.toString());
    }
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] → [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Т.к. в `f1` и `f2` текст типа String, то для сложения чисел `f1.getText() + f2.getText()` не обойтись (выдаст "1123"), поэтому здесь необходимо преобразование к типу `Int` через `Integer.ParseInt()`, чтобы выполнилось сложение, а потом к типу String.